# twig urlFor function

Tags: php, twig, slim

When I've tried to link anchor like this:

```
<a href="{{ urlFor('posts.show', {'postId': post.id}) }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
```

I had a fatal error:

```
Class 'Twig_SimpleFunction' not found
```

[image: 1]

But everything works perfect when I remove this link in the anchor. What could be the problem?

Comment: Which version of twig are you using ? please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `"Twig_SimpleFunction"` was introduced in the version between >1.11 and <=1.15, not in 1.x (as mentioned in the [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/deprecated.html)). That's a wrong information from the documentation.

Please try to install the version 1.15 for example.

This issue was already reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549729/error-class-twig-simplefunction-not-found-after-upgrade-to-symfony-2-2).

Comment: can I somehow replace this part of code in anchor with new version of this feature?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "replace this part of code in anchor with new version of this feature". Can you give me an example ? please

Answer (score 0):

Beware that `urlFor()` function is not defined by Twig. This means that your own project must define this function as a Twig extension before using it in a template.

If you are suing Symfony, the simplest solution is to change the custom `urlFor()` function by the built-in `url()` function:

```
<a href="{{ url('posts.show', {'postId': post.id}) }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
```

Comment: It is not tagged as Symfony